# how to implement Android favorite tab and save user data in a file / DB

Tags: java, android

I need to save some information from a screen and put it as user's favorite selection.
What is the best way to implement it?

For example, 
in one activity user selects A radio button and an item from spinner. Now i need to give them an option to mark this selection as favorite. 
Next time when they visit the fav tab, they can see the result instantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android you have several storage options. It depends if you think you're going to save complex things, or simple structures.

You can use [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) if you think you'll need something like a relational DB, or you can go for [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) if you're going to save primitive and simple values.

If those favs could grow, and you're going to save more things within the application, use a SQLite database that is very easy to manage.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a large number of items,you can use SQLite，there are series of tools to save data to DB.

Or,normally,just need to save a few items,you can use SharedPreferences and Json to save an Object.In this way,every time save data,you need change a object(objects) to a Json string.Looks like inefficiency,but works well.